# Shell give me this: proiect1.sh: 3: [: illegal number: ilir1477

Tags: bash, shell

```
read -p "Dati user:(0 for over) " user

while [ $user -ne "0" ]
 do
   FullName=`grep $user /passwd | awk -F: '{print $5}'`
   NrProcese=`ps | grep -c $user`

   echo -e "\nNumele userului: " $FullName "\nNumarul de procese pentru " $user ": " $NrProcese "\n"
   read -p "Dati user:(0 for over)" user
 done
```

Comment: What is the value of `user`?

Comment: ilir1477 or pair1478 and so on

Comment: How can `ilir1477` be compared numerically to `0`?

Comment: Luci, `-ne` is for **numerics** rather than **strings.** As per my answer, you need to use `!=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `user` variable is almost certainly invalid for the numeric comparison you're attempting. Insert the line:

```
echo "[$user]"
```

immediately before the `while` loop to check it.

If you *want* to be able to handle non-numeric users, you should use the string-based `!=` rather than the numeric-based `-ne`, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> xyzzy=plugh

pax> if [ $xyzzy -ne "0" ] ; then echo yes ; fi
bash: [: plugh: integer expression expected

pax> if [ $xyzzy != "0" ] ; then echo yes ; fi
yes
```

From the `bash` manpage (my italics):

> **string1 != string2**:
>
> True if the *strings* are not equal.
>
> **arg1 OP arg2:**
>
> OP is one of -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.
>
> These *arithmetic* binary operators return true if arg1 is equal to, not equal to, less than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than or equal to arg2, respectively. Arg1 and arg2 may be *positive or negative integers.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while [[ $user -ne 0 ]]
```

Note: I'm assuming you are passing a valid number in there - for `user`, I mean.  If you passed `ilir1477`, then it won't work, as your if statement is comparing a number, not a string.

Comment: @Luci I'm glad you resolved it...  could you please share with us what was the problem?

Comment: i have to print the full name of the readed user from terminal.

Comment: also i have to print the number of procceses for the same user